"Increasing the water pressure" in the old pipes in the Palace of Knossos
In the Palace of Knossos, Crete, Greece there is an old piping system partially preserved, with the following commentary:

Series of clay pipes with one end narrower than the other so that they could fit together, thereby increasing the water pressure and allowing it to flow more easily.

Does this description make technical sense, and if so, how does it work so it "increases the water pressure"?
I understand only the part "so that they could fit together" :)



Maybe something is lost in the translation. Anyway, interesting information about these can be found here.

From a Google translation of the Greek, I'd say that there is nothing wrong with the translation, the original reads the same.  The original author had a lack of understanding.

@user1683793 ... or that it was correct in Greek, but they used Google translate? :)

I agree with David here, it is probably a problem in translation or in the understanding of the author in Greek, which I don’t speak. It should probably read “The fitted pipes allowed for a pressurized water distribution system.”
A paper by Angelakis et al from Water mentions that this allowed water to flow up slopes.  The water first descended and then ascended through a bridge with an estimated inclination rate of 5% suggesting an application of the principle of communicating vessels.
This paper also proposes that these pressurized pipes were used for fountains, rather than general domestic use, especially as these pipes only supplied a limited amount of water, as they were quite small.
The hydraulic distribution system of the Minoans was adopted by the Greeks (Mycenaeans) who took over the island of Crete.

It looks like a translation ambiguity.
Having well-fitting pipe joints allows the use of higher pressure.
Also, there is always flow reduction as a result of joints, having good joints reduces the flow obstruction.
However, it's not clear what this is compared to: the original author may simply have expected the reader to be ignorant of the fact that pipe narrowing to make pipe joints is an obvious and historically common way of joining pipes. The Romans were exceptions rather than typical: they used concrete, and cement joints, because Rome was built on a geology that provide good material for concrete and cement.

No.  Nothing about that increases water pressure.
It is possible that the resulting joints had less pressure drop than whatever alternative existed for joining pipes, but making pipes smaller makes the flow velocity increase and leads to higher pressure drops.
